# asp.net gridview paging issue when rebinding it for a search result

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid view and I bind it on first page load , I have some searching optionst on the same page , when search button is clicked I query the seaarch and i rebind the gridview with the new datasource comming out of search result , the problem is after rebinding the gridview I have paging problems which I don't have them in the first pageload data binding ! could anyone tell me why is that ?!

Here is my Page_Load coe :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisableChaching();
    string val = Convert.ToString(Session["AccessLevel"]);
    if (Request.Cookies["UserName"] == null)
    {
        if (Session["UserName"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
        }
        else if (val   == "2")
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
        }
    }
    else if (val == "2")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
    }
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadControls();
        BindGrid();
    }
}
```

My GV_PageIndexChanging :

```
protected void GV_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{

    GV.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindGrid();
    PageStatus(Status.None);
}
```

my btnSearch_Click :

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
 {
query = new CommonQueries();
       GV.DataSource = query.getBooksByGroupIDSubGroupID(DrpGroup.SelectedItem.Value,DrpSubGroup.SelectedItem.Value);
     GV.DataBind();
 }
```

And in CommonQueries Class I have this query wich I used befor :

```
    public List<Book> getBooksByGroupIDSubGroupID(string GroupID, string SubGroupID)
{
    db = new BookMarketDataContext();
    List<Book> list = new List<Book>();
    list = (from b in db.Books where b.GroupID.ToString() == GroupID && b.SubGroupID.ToString() == SubGroupID  orderby b.Name select b).ToList();
    return list;
}
```

TO BE MORE SPECIFIC : On my Page loads I don't have any problem with gridview page changing 
BUT after clicking the search button "btnSearch" and rebinding the gridview , if search results are enough to cause the gridview to have pagenumbers , and when I click one of those page numbers I get wrong results from the previous page_Load !

Comment: You need to be more specific, maybe add some source code, screen shots and most importantly what is the exact nature of the problem, what does not work as expected.

Comment: @Constantin - I editted my question and explained more , I hope you can help me now !

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your postback on paging doesn't include information on which viewstate it should be paging. You should be pushing that information down to the page so that it can be included in the postback, or storing it in user session (less roundtrip, more weight on the server, but faster responses if you're also storing the query result)...

Comment: thank you for your answer , could you help me with some code please ? An example of what to do ?!

Comment: I don't know enough about the architecture of your site to give more prescriptive guidance and code; I would suggest that it could be as simple as pushing the search criteria into viewstate and checking for its presence when you run your paging event handler. If it's there and non-empty, make sure that you bind to the correct view of the data. This is going to require you to restructure your page a bit. I have to go write paying client code myself....

Comment: ok , thanks alot , I think I got your Idea ,I will work on It

Comment: Good luck. (Switching clients, had a chance to poke in to check).